# How to save data in the table to database using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I use Django 2.1 and Python 3.7.
I have some data in a table:

```
<table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
          <tr id="rec-1">
            <td><span class="sn">1</span>.</td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt1" value="Name"/></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2" value="0"/></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

A user can edit it and has to save it to the database in Django.
How can I do it? I am a beginner in Django. Can I do it using form or ajax or any other suggestions. But I want to keep this structure.

Comment: You can submit the form using ajax + djangorest

Comment: You can also use django forms,which is a better and simple option

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, Dan, Billal Begueradj, greg-449, Al Foиce ѫ, this is wrong what you did. The question is too simple and I need a help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a form or ajax. As long as the amount of data is relatively small (and this form is), I can't think of a downside to using `<form>` to upload the data.

**The Template**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
          <tr id="rec-1">
            <td><span class="sn">1</span>.</td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt1" value="{{ txt1}}"/></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2" value="{{ txt2}}"/></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

**The View**

```
def limitless(request):
    template = "limitless.html"
    context = {'txt1': "Name", 'txt2': 0}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        txt1 = request.POST.get("txt1")
        txt2 = request.POST.get("txt2")

        print(txt1 + "  " + txt2)
        #code to add variables to your models can go here
        context = {'txt1' : txt1, 'txt2': txt2}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: ohh thanks a lot, I will try to implement it.

Comment: It seems like I have a conflict. I have another method inside views.py which reads a file and then enters this data into the table. It has also a form and the method is "post". When I add the method "limitless" it calls another method.

Comment: Have you edited your URLs.py?

Comment: I have "path('', views.limitless, name='list')" in urls.py, and I have "{% include "project/limitless.html" %}" in the list.html file. "limitless" is both the name of method inside views.py and an html file (limitless.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
           <tr id="rec-1">
                <td><span class="sn">1</span>.</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="id_txt1" name="txt1" value="Name"></td>        
                <td><input type="text" id="id_txt2" name="txt2" value="0"></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>  
          </tr> 
          <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </form>
```

Notice that the **value** of  tag’s **name** attribute must be same as that of **field names** defined in your **model**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.